# Redirect to a new spreadsheet using Google app standalone script.

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-sheets-api

I have a standalone GAS which works with the Google Sheets. There is a case where a user could generate a new spreadsheet. I want to redirect the user automatically to the new spreadsheet as soon as it's been generated on the Google Drive.

For User Interface I use the [SpreadsheetApp.getUi()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getUi()).

So far I wasn't able to find a working solution to do it automatically. The only thing I have managed to do is to present the user with a link to the new spreadsheet so he can click and go to it.

Are there any working solutions or workarounds to redirect the user automatically in such situation?

Will much appreciate for any comments!

NOTE: The script should be in the Add-ons menu in the Googe Sheets. It has a couple of different screens (currently, modals) which present and take info for the user. Taking that into account I believe I won't be able to implement my script as Web App, since I have seen a couple of suggestions how to do it using GAS Web Apps.

Comment: There's no method to redirect user automatically when he is in Sheets UI, and I think it would never be implemented because of security reasons

Comment: You can open a dialog box, and have an "onload" event in the dialog box that opens a new browser tab using the new spreadsheet url, and then automatically close the dialog box. `<script>window.onload = function() {//open the new browser tab;google.script.host.close();}</script>`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Kos. What about some plain javascript functions, like "window.location" or something similar? Is there a way to execute them on the browser side or Google blocks that? I actually have tried to do it but no luck :(

Comment: @blisss05 as Sandy mentioned, you can call `showModalDialog` and open new tab from there

Comment: Thank you @Kos and @Sandy Good. I have managed to do something like this when displaying a modal `<body  onload="myFunction()"><script>function myFunction() {var a = document.createElement("a");a.target = "_blank"; a.href =  <theUrl >;  a.click();} </script></body>` It actually working and redirects to a new tab. However, the only limitation is that the browser (Chrome in my case) by default blocks it as a pop up. So  the user would need explicitly allow do proceed. I guess It's not very reliable solution but at least something.